# Magic square but with multiplication

Tags: magic-square

A 3x3 square is filled out with 9 positive integers such that the product of each row, column, and diagonals are equal. The sum of all 4 corners is less that 10. Find all possible configurations
In this case, a square cannot be rotated to make another one. You can repeat numbers too.
I thought of this as a systematic question, carefully writing down all possibilities, but that took way too long. Is there a faster way?

Comment: So you're allowed repetitions (which would make a square of only $1$'s allowed), but you're not allowed to make a square that is rotationally symmetric (which makes a square of only $1$'s not allowed after all). Is this right?

Comment: @Arthur No. Say i had the square (which is not a legitimate one that answers my question) (1st row): 123 (2nd row): 456 (3rd row): 789. Then I had the square (1st row): 369 (2nd row): 258 (3rd row) 147. These two would not be different squares because I can rotate one of them to become the other.\

Comment: @Arthur: I think OP means that rotations are not counted as distinct.  I would also ask—are reflections not counted as distinct as well?

Comment: There can't have been that many possibilities.  I can only come up with (a) all $1$'s, (b) all $2$'s, (c) $1, 4, 2; 4, 2, 1; 2, 1, 4$.  I used [this short white paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.211.28&rep=rep1&type=pdf) as a starting point, but instead of using the numbers directly, allowed zero elements, then used those elements as exponents to prime factors.  Does any prime besides $2$ work?

Comment: Reflections also don't count.

Comment: For a square with entries $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i$: Some identities are: $abc=e^3$, $ai=bh=cg=df=e^2$, $a^2=hf$, $c^2=dh$, $g^2=bf$, $i^2=db$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every magic multiplication 3x3 square is of the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{a}{b} & abc & \frac{a}{c} \\
\frac{ab}{c} & a & \frac{ac}{b} \\
ac & \frac{a}{bc} & ab
\end{bmatrix}$$
with the magic product $a^3$

If we assume all entries are integers, the square is rewritten as
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
ac & ab^2c^2 & ab \\
ab^2 & abc & ac^2 \\
abc^2 & a & ab^2c
\end{bmatrix}$$
with the magic product $a^3b^3c^3$

The sum of the corners is then $ac+ab+abc^2+ab^2c=a(1+bc)(b+c)<10$. Since $a,b,c$ must be positive integers, it follows that $1\leq a,b,c \leq 2$.

The only valid solutions are $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,2)$ corresponding to the squares:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 4 & 2 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
The last two squares actually just the same square rotated. So there are 3 possible such squares. Definitely not too many to count. 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 4 & 2 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$